# Check if two types are equal in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

How to check if types are equal in C++11?

```
 std::uint32_t == unsigned;  //#1
```

And another snippet

```
template<typename T> struct A{ 
  string s = T==unsigned ? "unsigned" : "other";
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use `std::is_same<T,U>::value` from C++11 onwards.

Here, `T`, and `U` are the types, and `value` will be `true` if they are equivalent, and `false` if they are not.

Note that this is evaluated at compile time.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same

Comment: How to test if two variable's data type are equal?

Comment: @Hzzkygcs `std::is_same<decltype(var1), decltype(var2)>::value`

Comment: Quite strangely though, `std::is_same<char, signed char>::value` returns 0 on my system, whereas `std::numeric_limits<char>::is_signed` is true (Intel-based Mac, macOS 12, Apple Clang 14.0.0).

Answer (score 4):

For fun, try this:

```
template<class T>
struct tag_t { using type=T; constexpr tag_t() {}; };
template<class T>
constexpr tag_t<T> tag{};

template<class T, class U>
constexpr std::is_same<T, U>  operator==( tag_t<T>, tag_t<U> ) { return {}; }
template<class T, class U>
constexpr std::integral_constant<bool, !(tag<T> == tag<U>)> operator!=( tag_t<T>, tag_t<U> ) { return {}; }
```

now you can type `tag<T> == tag<unsigned>`.  The result is both `constexpr` and encoded in the return type.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91302f40064c5a08).

Comment: it looks like you're overloading `operator==( tag_t<T>, tag_t<U> )` by return value. Isn't that not allowed?

Comment: @eric typo, the 2nd was meant to be `!=`.  I was also missing a space between `>` and `==`.

Answer (score 3):

In C++17, one can use:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T,U>) { /* do something*/ }
```