# How to tell if two variables have the same type at compile time?

Tags: c++, c++17

Is there a better way (or another way) to tell if two variables have the same type at compile time than this:

```
auto var1 = ..;
auto var2 = ..;
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(var1), decltype(var2)>::value);
```

Comment: Do you want to check two existing variables to have the same type or do you want to declare the second variable to have the same type as the first?

Comment: @gerum I think the title of the question strongly suggests the first. :)

Comment: What's wrong with that?  (except from changing from `::value` to `std::is_same_v`)

Comment: You should explain what is wrong with this way if you want a "better" way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a better way to tell if two variables has the same type at compile time?

No, [`std::is_same`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_same/) is the way to go. You could use of course `std::is_same_v`, as @L.F. commented, but that's basically the same philosophy.

> Is there another way to tell if two variables has the same type at compile time?

Yes, as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39665771/2411320).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way (or another way) to tell if two variables has
>   the same type at compile time than this:

Well, you can use the helper variable template [`std::is_same_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same)

```
template< class T, class U >
inline constexpr bool is_same_v = is_same<T, U>::value;
```

then it'll become

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(var1), decltype(var2)>);
```

Comment: on the other hand, that's literally the same thing but now requires C++17 rather than 11

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what the actual problem is here, but the simplest way to make sure that two variables have the same type is to write them that way:

```
int var1 = /* whatever */;
int var2 = /* whatever */; // var1 and var2 have the same type
```

if you're a fan of `auto` instead of writing the actual type, you can write code that simply defines the second variable with the same type as the first:

```
auto var1 = /* whatever */;
decltype(var1) var2 = /* whatever */; // var1 and var2 have the same type
```

another possibility is to write a template function that takes two arguments of the same type:

```
template <class Ty> void f(Ty var1, Ty var2) { /* do something */ }
f(var1_expression, var2_expression);
```

if the types of `var1_expression` and `var2_expression` are not the same the template instantation will fail.