# What is the function in type_traits to check if the type is const char*?

Tags: c++, c++17

I need to make a template function myPrintf that checks if the types are good with %d %f %s in given string.

I have found these two

```
std::is_integral_v<T> 
std::is_floating_point<T>
```

but I don't know how to check if the given argument is const char*

Does anybody know?

Thanks

Comment: [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if two types are equal in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664316/check-if-two-types-are-equal-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check whether types match exactly using [`std::is_same_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same). For example:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void foo(const T &t) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<const char*, T>) {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

**Note:** `std::is_same<A, B>::value` is equivalent to `std::is_same_v<A, B>`